# mapping JSON data within arrays

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm working on a project with React. Before I start, I'm a complete beginner and looked through the internet for a solution but didn't get any further.

My project is about a YouTube Channel where questions are being answered in the videos from people.

I have a webpage where you have multiple divs which represent Video 1, Video 2, Video 3... and when clicking on one div/video then all questions are listed from that YouTube-Video and when clicking on a question then a Video-Player shows and plays the YouTube video from at a given time.

All my questions and their timestamp links are stored in one JSON file.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Video 1",
        "video_leght": "00:50:00",
        "date": "20.05.2010",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "question": "Question 1 ",
                "url": "Link"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "question": "Question 2",
                "url": "Link"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "question": "Question 3",
                "url": "Link"
              }         
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Video 2",
        "video_leght": "01:00:00",
        "date": "14.07.2016",
        "questions":[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "question": "Question 1 ",
                "url": "Link"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "question": "Question 2",
                "url": "Link"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "question": "Question 3",
                "url": "Link"
              }        
        ]
    }
]
```

With the map function I was able to view the different videos (video 1, video 2...) but when I click on one of the videos, **I can't figure it out to show only the questions from the selected video** for example to show only the questions from Video 2.

This is how I used to show Video 1, Video 2, Video 3... (I imported DataList from the JSON file location)

```
 <div>
    {DataList.map((ListItem, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{ListItem.title)}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
```

Please bear in mind that I am a complete beginner, and simply telling me to read some page how something works will not help me much. Most of the time I learn by looking at the given code and understanding it how it works or explaining it to me in your own words.

I have a .js File called "**Pitanja.js**" and here are all Videos shown (Video 1, Video 2...):

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./Pitanja.module.css";
import DataList from "../data/video_list.json";
import { useNavigate, Outlet} from "react-router-dom";

function Pitanja() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  
  return (
    <div className={style.mainCard}>
      {DataList.map((ListItem, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(`/pitanja/${ListItem.id}`);
            }}
            key={index}
            className={style.Card}
          >
            <h3 className={style.Title}>{ListItem.title}</h3>
            <h3 className={style.video_leght}>{ListItem.video_leght}</h3>
            <h4 className={style.Date}>{ListItem.date}</h4>
          </div>
        );
      })}
       <Outlet/>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Pitanja;
```

When clicking one Video, then the webpage routes to a **Card.js** file where the questions should be shown from the selected Video:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DataList from "../data/video_list.json";
import style from "./Card.module.css";

import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import Pitanja from "../Pages/Pitanja";

function Card() {
  const [playUrl, setPlayUrl] = useState("");
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={style.ViewContent}>
      <div className={style.mainCard}>
        {DataList.map((ListItem, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => setPlayUrl(ListItem.url)}
              key={index}
              className={style.Card}
            >
              <h3 className={style.question}>{ListItem.Pitanja}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className={style.VideoPlayer}>
        <ReactPlayer url={playUrl} controls={true} playing={isPlaying} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Card;
```

My **App.js** contains the following code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";   
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Pitanja from "./Pages/Pitanja";    
import Card from "./components/Card";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";    

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="pitanja" element={<Pitanja />}>
          </Route>
            <Route path="pitanja/:id" element={<Card />} />              
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And navigation bar called **Nav.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import style from "./Nav.module.css";

function Nav() {
  const NavStyle = {
    color: "white",
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <h3>logo</h3>
      <ul className={style.nav_links}>
        <Link style={NavStyle} to={"/"}>
          <li>Pocetna</li>
        </Link>
        <Link style={NavStyle} to={"/pitanja"}>
          <li>Pitanja</li>
        </Link>        
      </ul>
      <input className="SearchBox"></input>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

I didn't do much regarding search function and other stuff...

This is the first page with the videos:
[image]

This is the second page with all the questions of that Video:
[image]

Comment: Please show your click handler code.

Comment: Suggestion: `DataList` and `ListItem` are generic names that carry very little meaning. I recommend finding a name that is more precise. Maybe `videos` for the list and `video` for an item in the list. The idea is to find names that are more descriptive to the meaning of what the data which the variable represents.

Comment: I didn't want to make everything complicated if I add too much info.. but I edited and added my 2 components if that's what you were asking for :)

Comment: You've passed an id into the url, why don't you just get that and use it to find your questions? Is this a question about how to use react-router?

Comment: It's about displaying only the objects from the 2nd array - Example to show only the questions from Video 2

Comment: @Said I appreciate that you don't want to make things complicated. However, your original version simplified too much and left out details we need to help.

Comment: When you do `navigate(`/pitanja/${ListItem.id}`)`, what component is loaded by your `Router`? You will need to show that component next. In fact, I recommend that you check out [mcve] for some tips on creating a code example that has enough details for us to help you but leaves out unecessary details. You are currently leaving out too much for us to help you give suggestions.

Comment: I really appreciate for all of the help. I added the rest of the code and hope it helps on how to list only the questions from i.e. Video 2 on a separate webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello React is also new to me but if i have understood you good you have problem with displaying questions and url for specific video. So i think your problem is that you have nested Array inside you JSON and you can not access it the way you are trying.
In Card.js component you are doing this:

```
{DataList.map((ListItem, index) => {
      return (
        <div
          onClick={() => setPlayUrl(ListItem.url)}
          key={index}
          className={style.Card}
        >
          <h3 className={style.question}>{ListItem.Pitanja}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

You can not access **ListItem.url** as it is inside another Array.

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {videos.map((video, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={video.id}>
            <div>{video.title}</div>
            <div>{video.video_leght}</div>
            {video.questions.map((q) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div key={q.id}>
                    <div>{q.url}</div>
                    <div>{q.question}</div>
                    <button onClick={() => console.log(q.url)}>click</button>
                  </div>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

******** Updated Codesandbox after your comment****
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-feather-v7kr7p?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. There are 80+ videos and in every video 30+ questions. That's why I thought to go with the way of opening a new webpage with the questions from that video instead of listing everything on onepage..  or is there maybe a better way of doing this? 

Comment: AH okay then i have updated codesandbox above you can check it out now i think it is what you need. Now when you click on button under video it will take you to that video questions...You can use **useParams** hook form react-routher for stuff like this. You can also make it so that you see the video there too very easy. I am glad i can help someone. :) Hope this helps you a little bit.